# vector space equation

Tags: vector-spaces

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Q: Let $\triangle ABC$, $\vec{BC}=\vec{a}, \vec{CA}=\vec{b},\vec{AB}=\vec{c}$ and
$\vec{P}=(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})\vec{c}+(\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c})\vec{a}+(\vec{c}\cdot\vec{a})\vec{b}$

Show that

(1).  If $\vec{P}=\vec{O}$ then $\triangle ABC$ is regular triangle

(2).  If $\triangle ABC$ is regular triangle then $\vec{P}=\vec{O}$

(3).  If $\triangle ABC$ is right-angle triangle then $\vec{P}=|\vec{a}||\vec{b}||\vec{c}|$

(4).  If  $\vec{P}=|\vec{a}||\vec{b}||\vec{c}|$ then  $\triangle ABC$ is right-angle triangle

Comment: Is $∘$ the scalar product?

Comment: As above: what is $\,a\circ b\,$ ? WHat is a "regular triangle"? Perhaps it was ameant an equilateral triangle?...And also, what is $\,\vec O\;$ ? The circumcenter or what?

Comment: $\circ$ : inner product ,  regular triangl=equilateral triangle

Comment: and $\vec{O}$ is zero vector

Comment: I think $\;\;\cdot\;\;$is dot product

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**
 We have $a+b+c=0$, so $c=-a-b$. Then,

(2) If $\Delta ABC$ is regular, we have $a\cdot b=|a|^2\cdot\cos(120^\circ)=b\cdot c=c\cdot a$, call this number $\lambda$, so that $P=\lambda\,(a+b+c)=0$.

(1) Write $c=-a-b$ in the equation we get $-\big((b\cdot b+2\,a\cdot b)a\,+\,(a\cdot a+2\,a\cdot b)b\big)\ =\ 0$. Then consider two cases: $a\parallel b$ and $a$, $b$ are linearly independent. In the latter case we can conclude that the coefficients must be $0$, i.e. $b\cdot b=-2\,a\cdot b=a\cdot a$.

(3) By symmetry, we can assume without loss of generality that $a\perp b$. Then, as $a\cdot b=0$, we have
$$P=0-(b\cdot b)\,a-(a\cdot a)\,b\,.$$
And use Pythagorean theorem for its length: $|P|^2=|b|^4\,|a|^2+|a|^4\,|b|^2$.

Comment: (4) seems a bit harder.. At least, with this method, using the equality gotten at (1) for $P$, it leads to a rather difficult expression... I'm still thinking about other ways of solving this..